# Netbeans IDE consume memory larger than in its memory monitor

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

[image]

On Windows10 64 bit & Netbeans 8.2 the Netbeans IDE shows about 218 MB memory consumption but in Windows Task manager it shows about 527 MB!

Is there any explanation for that, specillay the performance of the system is lost!

Answer (score 0):

RAM != Java heap space. [Here](https://plumbr.eu/blog/memory-leaks/why-does-my-java-process-consume-more-memory-than-xmx) is an article trying to explain the difference between memory usage and heap space usage. Hope this helps.